# ¿Por que un input tipo number no me devuelve el valor con punto?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy utilizando un `<input type="number"` y necesito obtener el `value` ingresado a medida que se tipea.

El problema se da cuando ingreso `"5."`.
Desde Javascript el valor que obtengo es `"5"`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('num')
console.log('Init value:', input.value)
input.addEventListener('input', _ => console.log('Change value:', input.value))
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" value="5." step="0.01" />
```

¿Como puedo hacer desde javascript para obtener `"5."`?

Comment: En JS, un valor numérico que ha sido "parseado" desde una cadena (el valor devuelto por el elemento `input` es una cadena) se hace hasta donde es posible "parsear" dicha cadena a número. Cuando escribes `5.` sin especificar ningún decimal, el valor que JS devuelve es el que se puede convertir en número (justo hasta antes del punto decimal. En el caso contrario (`.5`), JS usa un valor de cero como valor entero y los números después del punto como valor decimal.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, diría que no. Si inspecciono el elemento, el valor que obtengo es [una cadena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2ipM.png)

Comment: Si, pero el elemento es de tipo `number` por lo cual para poder determinar que el valor introducido es numérico debe "parsear" el mismo y devolver su valor de cadena correspondiente.

Comment: Saludos. Como bien mencionaron previamente; es un texto convertido en número. el numero **5.** no existe; si le agregas un número a la derecha (tenia izquierda error corregido disculpa) del punto entonces sí lo incluirá.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, estas sugiriendo que es correcto devolver `5` y no `5.` o `5.0`? Porque podría darse cuenta que es un decimal y devolver `5.0` tranquilamente. Si me baso en lo que dice la [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values), con indicar `step="0.01"` ya estoy diciendo que acepte decimales.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr ideal sería tener algo que respalde esto que comentan.

Comment: *sería tener algo que respalde esto que comentan*: pues en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) proporcionada por MDN sobre el elemento `input` de tipo `number` dice: *Éstos incluyen validación incorporada para rechazar entradas no numéricas.* Para poder rechazar estas entradas existe un patrón de expresión regular, que puedes consultar en [valid floating point number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number)

Comment: @MauricioContreras, justamente dice _rechazar entradas no numéricas_ y no lo rechaza, me deja ingresar el número. El valor `5.` es válido.

Comment: Es válido el punto, pero no lo deja como "valor" ya que el valor sólo permite números válidos. El hecho de que te permita introducir 1 punto decimal es para que puedas luego introducir más dígitos. El valor que hayas introducido siempre debe ser un valor válido, se considera válido si está completo, pero al tener el punto al final, el valor numérico no termina de ser válido, no te lo rechaza en la primera intoruducción, pero sí en las siguientes. El valor que se representa no puede ser inválido, es por ello que aunque te puestra `5.` en el input, su valor será sólo `5`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, me parece que podemos debatir durante horas, pero si yo le  pido que me diga si es valido usando  `input.validity.value`, devuelve `true`. Otra cosa más, si yo quisiera el valor como *número* podrías usar `input.valueAsNumber`. Yo quiero que me devuelva lo que esta escrito en el `input`

Comment: No uses un input numérico, sería la solución más obvia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) sobre el elemento y mediante una lógica sencilla añadir el punto para obtener el resultado que esperas. Sin embargo esto te puede traer problemas según la lógica que desees implementar.

Por ejemplo, detectando la tecla pulsada con [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('num')
console.log('Init value:', input.value);
let typedValues = '';
input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if(e.key.match(/[0-9.]/)) {
    if(e.key === '.') {
      if(!typedValues.includes(e.key)) {
        typedValues = typedValues.concat(e.key);
      }
    } else {
      typedValues = typedValues.concat(e.key);
    }
    console.log('Change value:', typedValues);
  }
  if(e.key === 'Backspace') {
    typedValues = typedValues.substring(0, typedValues.length - 1);
    console.log('Change value:', typedValues);
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" value="5." step="0.01" />
```

Otra forma sería agregando sólo el punto al valor devuelto y mostrarlo, sólo si el carácter introducido es el punto y el valor no lo incluye todavía.

Sin embargo, al eliminar valores, usando `backspace` vas a llegar al mismo resultado inesperado de tener visulamente `5.` y en consola sólo `5`. Hay formas de evitar esto mediante el uso de copias de la cadena, así, si por alguna razón, la cadena devuelta por el valor del `input` no contiene el punto final que hay en la copia, imprimes la copia en vez del valor.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('num')
console.log('Init value:', input.value);
input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let value = e.currentTarget.value;
  if(e.key === '.') {
    if(!value.includes(e.key)) {
      value = value.concat('.');
    }
  }
  console.log('Change value:', value);
});
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" value="5." step="0.01" />
```

Sobre la validación del valor introducido en el [elemento `input` de tipo `number`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)), la especificación de [número de punto flotante válido](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number), establece que:

> Una cadena es un número de punto flotante válido si consiste en:
>
> 1. Opcionalmente, un carácter `U+002D` HYPHEN-MINUS (`-`).
> 2. Uno o ambos de los siguientes, en el orden dado:
>
>    1. Una serie de uno o más dígitos ASCII.
>    2. **Ambos** de los siguientes, en el orden dado:
>
>       1. Un carácter U+002E FULL STOP (`.`).
>       2. Una serie de uno o más dígitos ASCII.
> 3. Opcionalmente:
>
>    1. Tanto un carácter U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E (`e`) o un carácter U+0045 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E (`E`).
>    2. Opcionalmente, un carácter U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (`-`) o un carácter U+002B PLUS SIGN (`+`).
>    3. Una serie de uno o más dígitos ASCII.

<sub>Traducción propia</sub>

Comment: Ojo, que hay que ser bastante cuidadoso con el guard. Lo tengo que ajustar, porque permite una salida con 2 puntos decimales: `2.2.3`, cosa que no es numéricamente correcta.

Comment: He ajustado la lógica del guard. Es a ese tipo de errores a los que me refiero en mi respuesta.

Comment: @Marcos he logrado una implementación medianamente aceptable. Supongo que se podrá mejorar, pero como te dije en un principio, va a depender de la lógica que apliques

Comment: Recíen me doy cuenta que actualizaste tu respuesta. Lo que respalda todo lo que hemos charlado en los comentarios es lo que dice en `2.2` y es lo que necesitaba para saber "porque". De verdad, gracias por tu ayuda